# Why does the Jupyter notebook display as a JSON file in VS Code？

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

It works well when I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + P then 'jupyter:create a new project'.

For this file, I used that function. One day I close VS Code and I found the 'ipynb' looks like 'json' when I open it again.

How can I make it back to a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Just to be clear: A jupyter notebook _is_ a json file, with specific structure that defines a notebook. So your file looks fine, your problem is how to get VS Code to understand that it is a notebook again, so that it is parsed and displayed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb", // if commented, will open as JSON
        // "*.ipynb": "default" //do not turn it on else will not open JupyterNB by default
```

Comment: This worked for me. But `jupyter.notebook.ipynb` is not an accepted value. Changing to `jupyter-notebook` is able to remove the warning message.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check that you are using the correct Jupyter extension.

   The [old donjayamanne.jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.jupyter) has now been merged into or replaced by the [ms-toolsai.jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter). Searching for "jupyter" in the extensions list should show both of them, with one of them marked as "(deprecated)".

   [image]

   If you still have the deprecated one, uninstall that, and install the new one. As mentioned in the old extension's description:

   > This extension is no longer being maintained and all of its functionality has been (or will be) placed into the Microsoft Jupyter extension.
   >
   > Please download the Microsoft Jupyter Extension instead.
2. Check that you have **Use Notebook Editor** enabled.

   From [Setting up your environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment):

   > By default, the Visual Studio Code Python extension will open a Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) in the Notebook Editor. If you want to disable this behavior you can turn it off in settings. (Python > Data Science: Use Notebook Editor

   The docs still mention the old setting, but as of VS Code 1.54 and with the new [Microsoft Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter), it should now be:

   ```json
   "jupyter.useNotebookEditor":true
   ```

   [image]
3. Check that you activated a Python environment with the Jupyter package.

   From [Setting up your environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment):

   > To work with Jupyter notebooks, you must activate an Anaconda environment in VS Code, or another Python environment in which you've installed the [Jupyter package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/). To select an environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (`⌘`+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+`P`).

   Open a terminal and check that you have `jupyter` and `ipykernel`:

   ```
   (venv) test$ jupyter --version
   jupyter core     : 4.7.1
   jupyter-notebook : not installed
   qtconsole        : not installed
   ipython          : 7.21.0
   ipykernel        : 5.5.0
   jupyter client   : 6.1.11
   jupyter lab      : not installed
   nbconvert        : not installed
   ipywidgets       : not installed
   nbformat         : not installed
   traitlets        : 5.0.5
   ```

   The Jupyter extension requires you to install `ipykernel`:

   ```
   (venv) test$ pip install ipykernel
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When Saving your notebook pick "All Files" instead of JSON.
[image: Pick All Files]

Your file will show up as a IPYNB

[image: Your file will show up as a IPYNB]

Comment: This saves an empty notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Change the corresponding editor association in your user or profile settings (JSON) like so:

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
},
```

Answer (score -4):

Change back the extension from a .`json` to `.ipynb`