# ipynb files opening in JSONformat in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to open ipynb files in VSCODE in Ubuntu. But the files are not opening as notebook editor. Instead it is showing as raw json format. can you please help?

Python version: 3.8
ipykernel=5.5.0

tried uninstalling the jupyeter extension but it did not work.

**Update:**

When I open a new notebook from the below command in vscode (via `ctlr+shift+p)`  and `Jupyter: Create Blank New Jupyter Notebook` it opens a new notebook as expected but I am unable to save the file. VSCode prompts the below message

> Test_Python_Folder/Untitled-1.ipynb is not supported by Jupyter.
>
> Please make sure the file name matches following patterns:

Thanks,
Dhinesh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Jupyter notebook display as a JSON file in VS Code？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517511/why-does-the-jupyter-notebook-display-as-a-json-file-in-vs-code)

Comment: @Sujay No. I tried all the options mentioned in that link. But it didn't work

Comment: Have you downloaded the Jupyter plugin on your vscode?

Comment: @DhanaD. Yes I downloaded and installed the extension from VSCode

Comment: Looks like this issue here, from the comments seems like re-installing might help? I believe that a solution is being worked on, but this might unblock you in the meantime: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this customer confirmation here: [Open ipynb on Visual Studio Code, display json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794306/open-ipynb-on-visual-studio-code-display-json) the current workaround is to re-install VS Code.

Comment: Thank you @Ian Huff . Worked after re-installing vs code.

Comment: This was only a temporary solution for me on multiple platforms. The fresh reinstall after full uninstall resulted in a different dialog box in Windows 11 for saving the file "As", however it disappeared after 3 days and only allows me to save as JSON, or anything but Jupyter. I replied to this thread, but it was deleted. Reposted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914361/save-as-ipynb-in-vscode.