# Open ipynb on Visual Studio Code, display json

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

When I open an **ipynb** file, I just see a json file. I tested with all files of :
https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/mslearn-ai900.git

I have on my machine :

- Python 3.9.6 installed
- Installed with `pip` command : `jupyterlab`, `notebook` and `voila`

On Visual Studio Code (version 1.59.0) :

- `Python 3.9.6 64-bit` is the current interpreter.
- I can create a new notebook : "CTRL+SHIFT+P --> Jupyter : Create new blank notebook"
  and I saw on the down-right "Jupyter Server:local". I can execute code : `print("Hello, Python!")`, but when I try to save file, I have this error :
  Failed to register 'Untitled-1' : File name `file:///*ThePathToSave*/Test.ipynb` is not supported by Jupyter.

Extensions installed :

- Jupyter v2021.8.1195043623
- Pylance v2021.8.1
- Python v2021.8.1105858891

List of kernel : (*command*) `jupyter kernelspec list`

```
Available kernels:
  .net-csharp        C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\.net-csharp
  .net-fsharp        C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\.net-fsharp
  .net-powershell    C:\Users\antho\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\.net-powershell
  python3            c:\python\python39\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like this issue here, from the comments seems like re-installing might help? I believe that a solution is being worked on, but this might unblock you in the meantime: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-install all Visual Studio Code.
I followed this answer to uninstall 'completely' VS Code :
https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely
and after, I re-install Visual Studio Code.
Now I can open all files.

Thanks to @IanHuff