# Why is my Jupyter Notebook opening as a JSON file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having some issues with displaying Jupyter notebooks in Visual Code. It used to show up properly before, but something must have happened and it shows up like a JSON string for some reason. The Visual Code is a local installation but I am using Remote Explorer to connect to a server that hosts the notebooks and scripts. I have attached a picture below as to what is code showing me

[image: Visual Code notebook display issue]

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Although I made sure the extensions for notebook renders are working properly but I am not confident that this is not the source of errors. I googled for a solution but not being able to describe the issue I couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517511/why-does-the-jupyter-notebook-display-as-a-json-file-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Jupyter notebook display as a JSON file in VS Code？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517511/why-does-the-jupyter-notebook-display-as-a-json-file-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of cache corruption. If you're able to run commands in the command palette, try running `Python: Clear cache and reload window`.

Comment: Thanks for your response I did that on Visual Code but the issue seems to be there... I am not sure if has got anything to do with the extensions... One thing I would like to mention is I am connecting to a server which hosts the notebooks and code